# Laravel eloquent and raw sql return different timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm getting different time in the created_at column from laravel eloquent and raw sql. The raw sql gives the correct time while the eloquent is wrong. I've already setup the timezone properly and clear config.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    //returns correct time created_at: "2020-12-08 19:44:30"
    $timelines = DB::select('select * from timelines where user_id = ?', [auth()->user()->id]);
    
    //returns wrong time created_at: "2020-12-08T11:44:30.000000Z"
    $timelines = Timeline::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->get();

    return $timelines;
}
```

**Model**

```
class Timeline extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

}
```

**Database**

```
{
    Schema::create('timelines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->foreign('user_id')->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade");
        $table->integer('source_id');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: What does you Timeline model look like? Post the class

Comment: Where are you actually echoing your timestamps? if you do a `dd($timelines->created_at)` what do you get? A carbon instance?

Comment: I already added the comment to show what i get when i do that. @bassxzero

Comment: dosent my answer solve your problem? if its you can accept my answer with the "Tick"

Comment: have you tried my suggested solution?

Answer (score 3):

The Raw Database returns correct time because DBMS time zone is correct.

but in Eloquent, `created_at` field converts into an `Carbon::class` instance by default.

and `Carbon::class` will use timezone configuration of your app to convert to real time.

so change in laravel `./config/app.php` :

```
'timezone' => 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur',
```

because i suppose you are in +8 Timezone based on your profile location,
and your reporting time log are 8 hours difference from **UTC** the default time zone config in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mutator to change format returned by eloquent

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
     return date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($value));
}
```

add this function in your Timeline model.

you can also modify function by using carbon methods

for more info you can refer to laravel docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#introduction